# How do I access my array in my method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Here is my issue.  I am trying to build an array of HomeLoan in my main, and then from my main, call the printHLoans(hLoans) from my main, so that I can list them and then add more functionality.  Unfortunately, it is saying that hLoan cannot be resolved as a variable.

Main Class

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LoanTest 
{
static int term;
static int loanID=0;
static int hHowMany=0;
static int cHowMany=0;
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter name: ");
    String name = input.nextLine();


    System.out.print("Enter Customer ID: ");
    int custID=0;
    do
    {
        try 
        {
            custID = input.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Customer IDs are numbers only");
            input.next();
        }
    }while (custID<1);   
    boolean aa=true;
    while(aa)
    {
        System.out.println("Do you have a (h)ome loan or a (c)ar loan?");
        String a = input.next();
        switch (a) 
        {
        case "h": System.out.println("You selected Home Loan");
                System.out.println("How many Home Loans would you like to enter?");
                hHowMany = input.nextInt();
                HomeLoan[] hLoans = new HomeLoan[hHowMany];
                int z=0;
                while (hHowMany>z)
                {

                hLoans[z] = new HomeLoan(name, custID);
                z++;
                }
                break;
        case "c": System.out.println("You selected Car Loan");
                System.out.println("How many Car Loans would you like to enter?");
                cHowMany = input.nextInt();
                int x=0;
                CarLoan[] carLoans = new CarLoan[cHowMany];
                while (x<cHowMany)
                {
                    System.out.print("Enter Loan ID: ");
                    loanID=0;
                    do
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            loanID=input.nextInt();
                        }
                        catch (InputMismatchException e)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Loan IDs are number only");
                            input.next();
                        }
                    }while (loanID<1);
                    boolean b=true;
                    while(b)
                    {

                        System.out.print("Enter term: ");
                        term=input.nextInt();
                        boolean t = CarLoan.termCorrect(term);
                        if(t){System.out.println("Error: Maximum of 6 year");}
                        else {b=false; System.out.println("You entered: " + term + " years");}
                    }
                carLoans[x] = new CarLoan(name, custID, loanID, term);
                x++;
                }
                break;
        default: System.out.println("Invalid input");
                break;
        }
        System.out.print("Would you like to enter another loan?");
        System.out.print("(y)es or (n)o:");
        String m = input.next();
        System.out.println("");
        switch (m)
        {
        case "y": break;
        case "n": aa=false;
                  break;
        default: System.out.print("Invalid entry");
        }
    }
    printHLoans(hLoans);

    System.out.println("Thank you for using Loan Software");
    System.out.println("Have a nice day");
}
public static void printHLoans(HomeLoan hLoans[])
{
    System.out.println("Here are the loans you entered . . .");
    int zzz=0;
    while (zzz<hHowMany)
    {
        term = hLoans[zzz].getTerm();
        loanID=hLoans[zzz].getLoanID();
        String address=hLoans[zzz].getAddress();
        double loanAmount = hLoans[zzz].getLoanAmount();
        System.out.print(zzz + ": ");
        System.out.print(hLoans[zzz].toString(loanID, address, term, loanAmount));
        System.out.println();
        zzz++;
    }
}
}
```

HomeLoan Class

```
 import java.util.InputMismatchException;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class HomeLoan extends Loan
 {
private String address;
int howMany;
private double loanAmount;
private int term;
private int loanID;

public HomeLoan()
{

}
public HomeLoan(String name, int custID)
{
    //super(name, custID, loanID);
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Loan ID: ");
    loanID=0;
    do
    {
        try
        {
            loanID=input.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Loan IDs are number only");
            input.next();
        }
    }while (loanID<1);
    boolean l=true;
    while (l)
    {

        System.out.print("Enter term: ");
        term=input.nextInt();
        boolean s = HomeLoan.termCorrect(term);
        if (s){System.out.println("Error: Maximum of 30 years");}
        else {l=false;}
    }
    //System.out.println();
    input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter your address: ");
    address=input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter loan ammount: ");
    loanAmount = input.nextDouble();
    double annualInterest = 10.99;
    double monthlyPayment = amortization(loanAmount, annualInterest, term);
    double newBalance=payment(monthlyPayment, loanAmount);
    //System.out.println("Payment: " + monthlyPayment);
    //System.out.println("New balance after payment: " + newBalance);

}
public static boolean termCorrect(int term)
{
    boolean a;
    if (term>30) {a=true; return a;}
    else {a=false; return a;}
}
public String toString(String name, int custID, int loanID)
{
    String display = "Name: " + name + " Customer ID: " + custID + " Address: "+ address+ " Loan ID: " + loanID + " Loan Amount: $" + loanAmount
            + " Current Balance: $";
    return  display;
}
public String getAddress()
{
    return address;
}
public double getLoanAmount()
{
    return loanAmount;
}
public int getTerm()
{
    return term;
}
public int getLoanID()
{
    return loanID;
}
public String toString(int loanID, String address, int term, double loanAmmount)
{
    String displa =  "ID: " + loanID + " Address:" + address + " Term: " + term + " Loan Ammount: " + loanAmmount;
    return displa;

}
private void equals()
{

}
public void printHLoans(HomeLoan hLoans[], int xxx)
{

}

}
```

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you've declared the `HomeLoan[] hLoans = new HomeLoan[hHowMany];` within the `while` loop and are trying to access it after that. That's why once the `while` loop is over, the `hLoans` goes out of scope. In your case, its more specifically within the `case "h"` of the `switch`, which further narrows down the scope of `hLoans` to just within it.

To be able to access it outside the `while`, you need to declare it at a scope higher than the `while`. Do something like this.

```
HomeLoan[] hLoans; // Before while
while(aa) {
...
   switch..
   case "h": hLoans = new HomeLoan[hHowMany];
}
printHLoans(hLoans);
```

Comment: Is there no way to pass it from there?

Comment: You could pass it from within the case itself, but that depends on your requirements. The best way would be to just declare it outside and initialize it wherever needed and pass it after the while, as you've already done.

Comment: Wont do exactly what I intended, but it will works.  thanks a ton